# Problema al cargar un imagen con codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

no me carga la imagen y no se que tengo mal gracias

```
        foreach ($adjuntos_documents as $adjuntos){
    echo "<div class='content_documents'>";
    echo  "<div class='document2'>";
    echo    '<img  alt="Adjunto" class="imgadjunto2" src=" base_url();css/images/adjuntar.png"/>';
    echo   "<h2 class='nombredocument2'>$adjuntos->adjunto</h2>";
    echo  "<input type='text' class='fechaagregado2' value='$adjuntos->fecha_adjunto' readonly/> ";      
    echo  " </div>";
    echo  " <br>";
    echo  "</div>  ";
```

}  ?>

Comment: ¿Si hay algún error de PHP o en la consola de JS puedes mostrarlo?
¿Puedes mostrar el HTML renderizado?

Answer (score 1):

En la línea donde cargas la imagen con el tag `<img>` no estás utilizando correctamente el atributo `src`. Es supuesto tener ahí la ruta a la imagen que deseas que sea mostrada, probablemente esta ruta viene dentro de tu objeto `$adjuntos_documents` si la ruta viene completa en tu objeto entonces puedes hacer algo como:

```
echo '<img  alt="Adjunto" class="imgadjunto2" src="' .$adjuntos->url. '"/>';
```

Si por el contrario necesitas de `base_url()` para completar tu enlace (porque en el objeto viene la ruta parcialmente) entonces, puedes hacer algo del estilo:

```
 echo '<img  alt="Adjunto" class="imgadjunto2" src="' .base_url($adjuntos->url). '"/>';
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio